# Hibernate map class as SuperClass and as atribute

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, mapping, persistence

hi i have this scenery:

- SuperClass.java
  -- 2 atributes
  -- 1 object Thing.java
  -- 1 String
- Car.java extends SuperClass
  -- 2 more atribute
  -- 1 ID
  -- 1 String

For now, i have mapped SuperClass as @MappedSuperClass
Here is ok.

I need to use a SuperClass as object in another class.

- AnotherClass.java
  -- This have a list of SuperClass.java

i need map this object into AnotherClass in one association table. With columns:
id_another_class, id_thing, string

Can i do ?
Can i use @MappedSuperClass or i will need change to another thing?

Any can help me plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The SuperClass kept with @MappedSuperClass

Created one DefaultImplSuperClass , extends SuperClass
 This is mapped with @Embeddable

In AnotherClass i have a List of DefaultImplSuperClass

this list has mapped with:
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable

and works.

If i wanna create AnotherClass2 , having a associated table with SuperClass.
Only i need to use a List of DefaultImplSuperClass and map this on @CollectionTable

Thkx